# How to find a length and used elements in array structured text

Tags: structured-text

`Array_Length_u8:=SIZEOF(SkippedElements_au8)/ SIZEOF(SkippedElements_au8[0]);`

I am using this formula to find the array length but its doesn't execute and always showing 256 as result

Comment: Is this array of structures? pointers? Strings?

Comment: array of integers

Comment: Show definition of `SkippedElements_au8`

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `LOWER_BOUND` and `UPPER_BOUND`.
For example:

```
ArraySize : DINT;
ThisIsAnArray : ARRAY[1..10] OF DINT;
ArraySize := ABS(UPPER_BOUND(ThisIsAnArray, 1) - LOWER_BOUND(ThisIsAnArray, 1)) + 1;
```