Beckhoff Twincat3 Structured text Dynamic Array size calculation
I writing a program that loops through an array to check Boolean alarm variable status's.
I want to dynamically generate the for loop count integer for ending the loop.
I have looked through Benchoff's Twincat 3 Documentation and cant find any generic SIZEOF() functions to generate the array size, for example
nArraySize := SIZEOF(Array);
another though is the Generate the Upper an lower bounds of the array to determine the size but I cannot find any functions to do this either.

Please provide some context, at least how "Array" is declared.

You can't really determine the size like that, the SIZEOF returns number of bytes the variable occupies. You are missing one step, divide the array size (byte count) with the base type, to determine how many slices of data you have:
nArraySize := SIZEOF(array)/SIZEOF(array[0]) - 1;

and then you can call the for loop as
for i := 0 to nArraySize by 1 do
   myArray[i] ...

This of course assumes your array starts at 0.
Upper and lower bounds can only be used on variable sized arrays. One way you could do something is have the array defined somewhere in your program, and then have a function or a method, that has the variable array as IN_OUT parameter, as required by the variable arrays:
myArray : ARRAY[5..10] of ST_MyDataType;

F_DoSomething
VAR_IN_OUT
    refArray : ARRAY[*] of ST_MyDataType
END_VAR

VAR
    nIteration
END_VAR

FOR nIteration := LOWER_BOUND(refArray,1) to UPPER_BOUND(refArray,1) by 1 do
    if refArray[nIteration].Something = TRUE then
...
END_FOR

and then call the function as is:
F_DoSomething(myArray);

One last way you could work is with memory access and pointers, but that gets a bit more complicated then, and is unsafe if not taken extra care of addresses.

Thanks, Your variable sized arrays link solved my issue as it reference the Upper_Bound and Lower_Bound Functions. I was trying to use these functions yesterday and was right clicking and selecting go to definition although it wouldnt take me to the definition.
The Awnser in this stack exchange conversation has a simple method of finding array size provided by Jakob. You provided the link to the function definitions. Thanks
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64692329/how-to-find-a-length-and-used-elements-in-array-structured-text

One more thing, you mentioned you were using dynamically created array. If you mean using the __NEW keyword, this type of array must not be passed as a parameter to variable sized array arrTest : ARRAY[*]. Another thing, the post you mention shows using LOWER_BOUND and UPPER BOUND on a fixed array, as far as I know, you can only use them on variable sized array, aka [*], you will get a compilation error otherwise (not sure if it worked in 2020 and they changed it now).
